# How to get value of team member field that is a classification in sitefinity 12 web services using odata and javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, odata, sitefinity

I am using ajax to query web services in sitefinity I can successfully pull a teammembers data with this apiURL:

```
localhost/api/lawyerswebservice/teammembers?$expand=RelatedTeam,PrimaryImage;
```

However I can't get access to any fields that are classifications.  For example if i do the following query:

```
localhost/api/lawyerswebservice/teammembers?$expand=PositionTypes;
```

I get the console error:

```
{"error":{"code":"Unknown","message":"Property 'PositionTypes' on type 'Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.Team.TeamMember' is not a navigation property or complex property. Only navigation properties can be expanded."}}
```

Any advice on how to get his data would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to Advanced Settings => Web Services => [Your Service] => Types =>
  [Your Type] => Property Mappings
- Add new Navigation Property mapping.
- Enter the name for the new property.It should be unique.
- For Resolver Type enter
  "Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.Services.Contracts.TaxonomyRelationResolver"
- Add a parameter with key "propName" and value the name of taxonomy
  field (for ex. "Categories")
- Save Changes

**REF**: https://www.eveliko.com/blogs/blog-details/public/2017/06/06/exposing-taxonomy-field-in-sitefinity-odata-service

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

By default, classification fields are not returned in the results.

Explanation can be found in the

administration > settings > advanced > webServices > routes > frontend > services > yourservice > types > yourtype > property mappings > PositionTypes

There you will find a checkbox Selected by default which is unchecked.

The description is:

"This is a setting that determines which properties will be returned implicitly when querying the service type. E.g. Tags and Categories are not SelectedByDefault as they are properties which cause db queries and will be an overhead if they are selected by default for a large amount of items."

If you check it, then the service will start returning the Id of the selected taxon, which then you should be able to get its title.